# How to check if subprocess has finished?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am starting a process by doing:

```
for i in range(1, processes + 1):
            hup = MyURLParser() //A class I made
            p = Process(target = hup.run)
            p.start()
```

After that, so that the main thread doesn't exit immediately I do:

```
 while (True):
        print("Main sleeping...")
        sleep(20)
```

Instead of doing this, how can I check that each of the child processes are still running from the main thread ? Then instead of having the infinite loop I can break out of the loop at the right time and do something else....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`p.is_alive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.is_alive) tells you whether the process is running.

To wait until it's ended, use [`p.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join).

Answer (score 5):

Add all processes to a list, and [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) each of them in turn:

```
processes = []
for i in range(1, processes + 1):
    hup = MyURLParser() //A class I made
    p = Process(target = hup.run)
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

The `join()` call blocks until the process is finished. It doesn't matter in which order you call them; calling `join()` on a process that's already complete will just return immediately.

You may also want to check out the other functionality in the [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html); in particular the `Pool` class might help you simplify this code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `join` method (read more in [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process)):

First, keep the `Process` objects you create:

```
your_processes = []
...
   p.start()
   your_processes.append(p)
```

After starting all your processes, use `join` to wait each one of them to finish executing.:

```
for p in your_processes:
    p.join()
... #the rest of your code
```

Basically `join` makes the main process wait for process p to finish and only then to proceed to the next line of code.

Comment: This approach won't work because processes do not share local or global variables.

Comment: See here for more details:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490368/pythonappending-to-the-same-list-from-different-processes-using-multiprocessing

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
P = []
for i in range(1, processes + 1):
            hup = MyURLParser() //A class I made
            p = Process(target = hup.run)
            p.start()
            P.append(p)

for p in P:
            p.join()
```

To only check if the process is alive, use `.is_alive()`

Read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html