# Python: Multithreaded list append does not work as expected

Tags: python, multithreading

Why is the following code (you can run it [here](https://repl.it/@CP8/PhonyGlossyKnowledge)):

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from time import sleep

MY_LIST = []


def worker(j):
    global MY_LIST
    sleep(1)
    MY_LIST.append(j)
    print(j, len(MY_LIST))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parameters= [1, 2, 3, 4]
    with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, parameters)
```

prints:

```
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 2
```

And if I comment out the `sleep(1)` part, it prints what I expect:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

How can I fix the code so that it correctly appends and in the end I have 4 elements in `MY_LIST`

Comment: Curiously, this code won't execute for me. I get `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'worker' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>`

Comment: @SamMorgan try this: https://repl.it/@CP8/PhonyGlossyKnowledge

Comment: What is your goal? You probably need to use some synchronization mechanism when it comes to have several workers in parallel.

Comment: Looks like a timing issue. `pool.map` splits the iterable into chunks and submits these as individual tasks to the workers. My guess is that in the version without the `sleep` one of the workers quickly grabs all four tasks and executes them whereas the version with the `sleep` allows for both workers to pick up two of the tasks each. You can `print(multiprocessing.current_process().name, j, len(MY_LIST))` in the `worker` function to see if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a race which is revealed by the call to `time.sleep` because without it one of the workers finishes the task before any of the rest can even start. This is made clear if you use a longer list, for example:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from time import sleep

MY_LIST = []

def worker(j):
    global MY_LIST
    sleep(1)
    MY_LIST.append(j)
    print(j, len(MY_LIST))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parameters = range(25)
    with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, parameters)
```

Will output something like

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
1 10
1 11
1 12
1 13
1 14
1 15
1 16
1 17
1 18
1 19
1 20
1 21
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

Of course that's not the only problem. The other issue is that [global variables are not shared between processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42490484/10659910), at least not the primitive python types. You need to use a [`multiprocessing.Manager.List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager) or similar, something like this:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock, Manager
from time import sleep

manager = Manager()
MY_LIST = manager.list()

def worker(j):
    global MY_LIST, lock
    MY_LIST.append(j)
    print(j, len(MY_LIST))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parameters = range(25)
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, parameters)
```

Which will output

```
4 1
5 2
6 3
7 4
8 5
9 6
10 7
11 8
12 10
13 11
0 10
1 13
14 12
2 15
15 15
3 16
16 18
17 19
18 20
20 20
19 22
24 23
21 23
22 24
23 25
```

Of course this does nothing to guarantee order, only access.

Answer (score 1):

With `mutliprocessing`, you would need to use a shared variable in order to access it from multiple processes. In your code, without the `sleep`, each process finishes fast enough so that you only need to use one process in the pool and so your code appends to the same `MY_LIST`. When you use a sleep, it uses more than one process and so you end up appending to different instances of `MY_LIST`.

You will need to use a shared variable in order to access it from each process. The shared variable would need a preallocated size:

```
from multiprocessing import pool, Array, current_process

MY_LIST = Array('i', 8)

def worker(j):
    MY_LIST[j-1] = j*j
    print(current_process().name, j, len(MY_LIST))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parameters= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    with pool.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, parameters)
    for i in MY_LIST:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
ForkPoolWorker-1 1 8
ForkPoolWorker-2 2 8
ForkPoolWorker-1 4 8
ForkPoolWorker-3 3 8
ForkPoolWorker-1 5 8
ForkPoolWorker-2 6 8
ForkPoolWorker-1 7 8
ForkPoolWorker-3 8 8
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
```