# Is there a way to optimize the for loop? Selenium is taking too long to scrape 38 pages

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, optimization

I'm trying to scrape https://arxiv.org/search/?query=healthcare&searchtype=allI through the Selenium and python. The for loop takes too long to execute. I tried to scrape with headless browsers and PhantomJS, but it doesnt scrape the abstract field (Need the abstract field expanded with the more button clicked)

```py
import pandas as pd
import selenium
import re
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

browser = Firefox()
url_healthcare = 'https://arxiv.org/search/?query=healthcare&searchtype=all'
browser.get(url_healthcare)

dfs = []
for i in range(1, 39):
    articles = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('li[class="arxiv-result"]')

    for article in articles:
        title = article.find_element_by_tag_name('p[class="title is-5 mathjax"]').text
        arxiv_id = article.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text.replace('arXiv:','')
        arxiv_link = article.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[0].get_attribute('href') 
        pdf_link = article.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[1].get_attribute('href')
        authors = article.find_element_by_tag_name('p[class="authors"]').text.replace('Authors:','')

        try:
                link1 = browser.find_element_by_link_text('▽ More')
                link1.click()
        except:
                time.sleep(0.1)

        abstract = article.find_element_by_tag_name('p[class="abstract mathjax"]').text
        date = article.find_element_by_tag_name('p[class="is-size-7"]').text
        date = re.split(r"Submitted|;",date)[1]
        tag = article.find_element_by_tag_name('div[class="tags is-inline-block"]').text.replace('\n', ',')
        
        try:
            doi = article.find_element_by_tag_name('div[class="tags has-addons"]').text
            doi = re.split(r'\s', doi)[1] 
        except NoSuchElementException:
            doi = 'None'

        all_combined = [title, arxiv_id, arxiv_link, pdf_link, authors, abstract, date, tag, doi]
        dfs.append(all_combined)

    print('Finished Extracting Page:', i)

    try:
        link2 = browser.find_element_by_class_name('pagination-next')
        link2.click()
    except:
        browser.close
        
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: The scraped df should have 9 columns for each articles: title, id, link, pdf link, authors, abstract, date tags, doi.  So the resultant df should be (1890 X 9).
I need help with the abstract link, as it has a more button which when clicked gives the expanded abstract, which I require and I'm having trouble extracting it!

Comment: @J_T see my solution below. You can directly extract the full abstract content without clicking on more. The approach will certainly be faster than selenium.

Comment: How can I get all links at one shot? The link allows only a max of 200 articles. So, I'll have to use selenium for pagination after 200 rows? 
Really appreciate your help, Thanks man!

Comment: looks like max page size is 200. if you know exactly how many rows, you can just change the 'start' parameter from 0 to 200. This will return the next 200 items.

Comment: I need it for all 1890 rows

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post. This includes making edits to the post which invalidate existing answers or otherwise make your question unanswerable.

Comment: Sincere apologies, I was later informed that the code is private. I don't have permission to share it.

Comment: @user1234 To remove the content, the copyright holder or their agent will need to issue a DMCA takedown notice in the prescribed manner. Given that you say you didn't have the right to post the code, that means it's someone else who needs to issue the DMCA takedown notice. That doesn't mean we're not willing to work with you to have a question which remains a valid question, doesn't invalidate answers, and doesn't include the code you're concerned about. However, given the specifics of this question and answers, that's not going to be trivial (i.e. it's a lot of work on your part).

Comment: The most likely solution which accomplishes all three things is for you to re-write the code in the question into new code which both A) still exhibits the same issue, and B) doesn't include any of the code you feel you're not permitted to share, and which isn't a derivative work of that code. You will then need to get agreement from the people who answered for you to integrate your new code into their answer while still maintaining the quality of each answer and that it fixes the issue in the same manner as it did originally (e.g. get agreement by suggesting an edit to each).

Comment: I should probably also point out that even if it's taken down from here, there will still be copies on multiple archive sites and multiple sites which mirror SO content. SO has no control over those third-party sites, so the copyright holder will need to find and deal with each one separately. While removing it from here will reduce its visibility, it *definitely* won't remove it from the internet. Removing it completely from everywhere will be a significant undertaking, and may not be possible (i.e. it's *hard* and a lot of time/effort).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following implementation achieves this in **16 seconds**.

To speed up the execution process I have taken the following measures:

- Removed `Selenium` entirely (No clicking required)
- For `abstract`, used `BeautifulSoup`'s output and processed it later
- Added `multiprocessing` to speed up the process significantly

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

start_time = time.time()

def get_no_of_pages(showing_text):
    no_of_results = int((re.findall(r"(\d+,*\d+) results for all",showing_text)[0].replace(',','')))
    pages = no_of_results//200 + 1
    print("total pages:",pages)
    return pages 

def clean(text):
    return text.replace("\n", '').replace("  ",'')

def get_data_from_page(url,page_number,data):
    print("getting page",page_number)
    response = requests.get(url+"start="+str(page_number*200))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    
    arxiv_results = soup.find_all("li",{"class","arxiv-result"})

    for arxiv_result in arxiv_results:
        paper = {} 
        paper["titles"]= clean(arxiv_result.find("p",{"class","title is-5 mathjax"}).text)
        links = arxiv_result.find_all("a")
        paper["arxiv_ids"]= links[0].text.replace('arXiv:','')
        paper["arxiv_links"]= links[0].get('href')
        paper["pdf_link"]= links[1].get('href')
        paper["authors"]= clean(arxiv_result.find("p",{"class","authors"}).text.replace('Authors:',''))

        split_abstract = arxiv_result.find("p",{"class":"abstract mathjax"}).text.split("▽ More\n\n\n",1)
        if len(split_abstract) == 2:
            paper["abstract"] = clean(split_abstract[1].replace("△ Less",''))
        else: 
            paper["abstract"] = clean(split_abstract[0].replace("△ Less",''))

        paper["date"] = re.split(r"Submitted|;",arxiv_results[0].find("p",{"class":"is-size-7"}).text)[1]
        paper["tag"] = clean(arxiv_results[0].find("div",{"class":"tags is-inline-block"}).text) 
        doi = arxiv_results[0].find("div",{"class":"tags has-addons"})       
        if doi is None:
            paper["doi"] = "None"
        else:
            paper["doi"] = re.split(r'\s', doi.text)[1] 

        data.append(paper)
    
    print(f"page {page_number} done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://arxiv.org/search/?searchtype=all&query=healthcare&abstracts=show&size=200&order=-announced_date_first&'

    response = requests.get(url+"start=0")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

    with Manager() as manager:
        data = manager.list()  
        processes = []
        get_data_from_page(url,0,data)


        showing_text = soup.find("h1",{"class":"title is-clearfix"}).text
        for i in range(1,get_no_of_pages(showing_text)):
            p = Process(target=get_data_from_page, args=(url,i,data))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)

        for p in processes:
            p.join()

        print("Number of entires scraped:",len(data))

        stop_time = time.time()

        print("Time taken:", stop_time-start_time,"seconds")
```

Output:

```
>>> python test.py
```

```
getting page 0
page 0 done
total pages: 10
getting page 1
getting page 4
getting page 2
getting page 6
getting page 5
getting page 3
getting page 7
getting page 9
getting page 8
page 9 done
page 4 done
page 1 done
page 6 done
page 2 done
page 7 done
page 3 done
page 5 done
page 8 done
Number of entires scraped: 1890
Time taken: 15.911492586135864 seconds
```

Note:

- Please write the above code in a `.py` file. For Jupyter notebook refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47374811/11573842).
- Multiprocessing code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42490484/11573842).
- The ordering of entries in the `data` list won't match the ordering on the website as `Manager` will append `dictionaries` into it as they come.
- The above code finds the number of pages on its own and is thus generalized to work on any arxiv search result. Unfortunately, to do this it first `gets` `page 0` and then calculates the `number of pages` and then goes for `multiprocessing` for the remaining pages. This has the disadvantage that while the `0th page` was being worked on, no other process was running. So if you remove that part and simply run the loop for `10 pages` then the time taken should fall at around **8 seconds**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with request and beautiful soup approach. No need to click more link.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# you can change the size to retrieve all the results at one shot.

url = 'https://arxiv.org/search/?query=healthcare&searchtype=all&abstracts=show&order=-announced_date_first&size=50&start=0'
response = get(url,verify = False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
#print(soup)
queryresults = soup.find_all("li", attrs={"class": "arxiv-result"})

for result in queryresults:
    title = result.find("p",attrs={"class": "title is-5 mathjax"})
    print(title.text)

#If you need full abstract content - try this (you do not need to click on more button
    for result in queryresults:
        abstractFullContent = result.find("span",attrs={"class": "abstract-full has-text-grey-dark mathjax"})
        print(abstractFullContent.text)
```

**Output:**

```
 Interpretable Deep Learning for Automatic Diagnosis of 12-lead Electrocardiogram
            
  Leveraging Technology for Healthcare and Retaining Access to Personal Health Data to Enhance Personal Health and Well-being
  Towards new forms of particle sensing and manipulation and 3D imaging on a smartphone for healthcare applications
```