# populating a large dictionary using multiprocessing

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

The overall topic of this question is to create a dictionary based on another pre-existing one using multiprocessing.
I have a dictionary, called iddic. I want to create another dictionary, finaldic.

Now, here are the specifics of my problem. Here is how my code looks:

```
import multiprocessing

def create_initial_dictionary():
    #this function creates the large iddic dictionary
    global iddic
    #i write out a template for what iddic looks like for your use
    iddic = {'celia' : 14, 'pierre' : 12, 'picasso' :11, 'pikachu' :19}

def initialize_final_dic():
    global finaldic
    finaldic = {}

def populate_dictionary(names):
    #this function should use iddic to populate finaldic.
    for nam in names:
        finaldic[nam] = 2 * iddic[nam]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_initial_dictionary()
    initialize_final_dic()

    list_1 = list(iddic.keys())[:2]
    list_2 = list(iddic.keys())[2:]

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=populate_dictionary, args=(list_1,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=populate_dictionary, args=(list_2,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    
    print(finaldic)
```

finaldic should look like this:

```
finaldic = {'celia' : 28, 'pierre' : 24, 'picasso' :22, 'pikachu' :38}
```

This is the error I get:
NameError: name 'iddic' is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending to the same list from different processes using multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490368/appending-to-the-same-list-from-different-processes-using-multiprocessing)

Comment: Can you share expected result?

Comment: i would like the code to print finaldic (i dont really care if its printed tbh, just that it runs, which would mean i can add the next bit of code to this one)

Comment: i am looking at your link nokla

Comment: Can you share expected  `finaldic` data?

Comment: @nokla - you are right that solves the shared state for finaldic, but does not teach me how to make iddic available to the processes - or do I have to make all global variables, whether i want to change them or not, managers?

Comment: If you want to use a variable in different processes, you will need to implement some form of synchronization mechanism. Please read the [attached](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes)

Comment: i have just added what i believe finaldic should look like @Alderven

Comment: Take a look at the Manager class from the *multiprocessing* module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do multiplication within separate threads and then merge output dicts in the main thread:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def populate_dictionary(dict_, names):
    for name in names:
        dict_[name] = 2 * dict_[name]
    return dict_


input_dic = {'celia': 14, 'pierre': 12, 'picasso': 11, 'pikachu': 19}    
pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)
res1 = pool.apply_async(populate_dictionary, (input_dic, list(input_dic.keys())[:2]))
res2 = pool.apply_async(populate_dictionary, (input_dic, list(input_dic.keys())[2:]))

final_dic = res1.get() | res2.get()
```

Output:

```
{'celia': 28, 'pierre': 24, 'picasso': 22, 'pikachu': 38}
```

Comment: what part is inside the if name == main? thx for your answer btw

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__'` is not necessary